# How can i set the max length of a value / variable

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables, textbox

Hello im having a problem with my flash file. I have a value where when u press a button it raise by 0.2 but when i have raised it 3 times so it equals 0.6 but when i put the variable inside a text box it shows the following (times i have raised the value by clicking the button):
1: 0.2
2: 0.4
3: 0.6000000000000000
4: 0.8
5: 1
6: 1.2
7: 1.4
8: 1.5999999999999999

so for some reason it dosent raise by 0.2 or it do but not all the time... so can anyone help me how to set the max length of a value or how to fix this? so it raise by 0.2 every time :)

my code for the button:

```
shop_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,shop_1_c);
function shop_1_c(e:MouseEvent){
    if(ep >= 25){
    ep_per_second = ep_per_second+0.2;
    ep = ep-25;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`Number.toFixed()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html#toFixed%28%29). That will allow you to select how many digits are in a number. This will return a string version of the number that is rounded to the decimal place specified in the argument. The value in the string may not be the same as the value in the original number (i.e. `3.18.toFixed(1) = "3.2"`, not 3.1 or 3.18)

If the value is being entered by the user, you can also look at [`TextField.maxChars`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#maxChars), which will limit how many characters may be entered into a TextField (most other text inputs have an identical property as well).

Comment: If that answered your question, please mark the question as correct (the arrow under the number next to the answer). It will effectively close out the question and help keep the system clean.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by "...will actually modify the number". the `toFixed()` will return a stringified version of the number *rounded* to the supplied precision, however the actual `Number` is unaffected.

Comment: @32bitkid You are correct. I explained it poorly. I will update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Again thank u so many times :) the reason i dident check it as correct was because i could not :P at that time i was way too fast said it ^^ but again thanks for the help! :D